# Assigning Values within a dynamically named matrix in R

Tags: r, dynamic, eval, assign, r-raster

I am struggling with a loop in R where I have to use dynamic variable names (which I am told is a bad idea from the other posts about dynamic variable names, but I am pretty sure that I need to based on my file structure). Each folder for which the loop enters, there is a different number of files.

The dynamic variable names contain matrices and I need to look in each row/column of the matrix and output a new matrix.

Streamlined example:

```
 var 1 is a matrix(0,40,40) 
 var 2 is a matrix(0,45,45) 
 var 3 is a matrix(0,40,40) 

For (f in 1:(length of var3s))  # the number of files in the folder, in each folder: 

For (g in 1: ncol(var1)) {  
  For (h in 1: nrow(var1)) {
    if (var 1[g,h]>4 & var 2[g,h]<1)
          { var3[f] [g,h]<-1}    # <- you cannot do this, but this is ultimately what I want 
}
}
```

I want to take the f-th variable matrix from variable 3's list and assign a value to the location at [g,h]
I've done this before with real variable names, but I am struggling with adding the dynamic element. This is what it looks like and the errors I'm getting.

```
for (f in 1:(length(LD139_040))){
  assign(paste0("LD139_040s",f),
  matrix(0,nrow(eval(parse(text=paste0("B139_040",f)))),
  ncol(eval(parse(text=paste0("B139_040",f)))))) # this effectively creates my new matrix (var3 above) the size I need based on the files above

for (g in 1:(ncol(eval(parse(text=paste0("B139_040",f)))))){
  for (h in 1:(nrow(eval(parse(text=paste0("B139_040",f)))))){
  if (S139_040[g,h]>10 & 
  (assign(paste0("LD139_040",f), as.matrix(raster(LD139_040[f]))))[g,h]>.295 & 
  (assign(paste0("LD139_040",f), as.matrix(raster(LD139_040[f]))))[g,h]<.33 &  
  (assign(paste0("B139_040",f), as.matrix(raster(Blue139_040[f]))))[g,h]<180) 
    # this section also works and will give me a t/f at each location [g,h]
    # if true, assign the value 1 to the new matrix LD139_040 at f
  {assign(paste0("LD139_040s", f)[g,h], 1)}

   }
  }
}
```

I have tried a variety of combinations of eval and assign to organize the last statement, and I get errors such as 'invalid first assignment', incorrect number of dimensions, and target of assignment expands to non-language object.

Thanks for your help!

R version 3.1.1 "Sock it to Me" with library(raster)

Answer (score 0):

This did not require dynamic variable names. At each iteration within the loop the all of the names will change at the same time.

For example, this is how I answered the section in code block 2:

```
for (f in 1:(length(LD139_040))){
    currenttile<-LD139_040[f]
    Blue<-B139_040[f]
    newmatrix<- matrix(0,nrow(Blue),ncol(Blue))
    for (g in 1:(ncol(B139_040[f]))){
      for (h in 1:(nrow(B139_040[f]{
       if (S139_040[g,h]>10 & currenttile[g,h]>.295 & currenttile[g,h]<.33 & Blue [g,h]<180)
       {newmatrix[g,h]<-1}
     }
    }
   }
```

Put even more simply, since I learned that as long as the matrices are the same dimensions, you do not have to loop through each location:

```
for (f in 1:(length(LD139_040))){
    currenttile<-LD139_040[f]
    Blue<-B139_040[f]
    newmatrix<- matrix(0,nrow(Blue),ncol(Blue))
    currenttile[currenttile >.295 & currenttile <.33]<- 1
    Blue[Blue<180]<- 1
    newmatrix[Blue==1 & currenttile==1]<- 1 
   }
```

So thanks to everyone who tried to decipher this, it was a confusing problem for me to it took a while to figure out how to best approach it, (and obviously how to explain it). I hope this helps someone!